# Angular 15 role-based protection and message to user

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using Angular 15, I maintain user routes as below.
The protection works very well, but there is a small problem.
The page still opens when the user does not have the "CompanyRole" privilege.

So if the user has no authorization, how can I get console.log(' ') to write a message in the console?

I've been researching this situation for a week, but I couldn't solve it in any way.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
    const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: '', component: AppLayoutComponent,
        children: [
          { path: '', loadChildren: () => import('./applications/components/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule), canActivate: [RoleGuard], data: {roles: ['DashboardRole', 'AdminRole'] } },
          { path: 'company', loadChildren: () => import('./applications/components/company/company.module').then(m => m.CompanyModule), canActivate: [RoleGuard], data: {roles: ['CompanyRole'] }},
          { path: 'inventory', loadChildren: () => import('./applications/components/inventory/inventory.module').then(m => m.InventoryModule) },
          { path: 'category', loadChildren: () => import('./applications/components/category/category.module').then(m => m.CategoryModule), canActivate: [RoleGuard], data: {roles: ['CategoryRole'] }},
          { path: 'brand', loadChildren: () => import('./applications/components/brand/brand.module').then(m => m.BrandModule), canActivate: [RoleGuard], data: {roles: ['BrandRole'] } }
        ], 
      },

      { path: 'auth', loadChildren: () => import('./applications/components/auth/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthModule)},

      { path: 'notfound', component: NotfoundComponent, canActivate: [RoleGuard]}, //AuthGuard
      { path: '**', redirectTo: '/notfound', canActivate: [RoleGuard]} //AuthGuard
    ];
```

**RoleGuard**

```
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  import {ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree} from '@angular/router';
  import {AuthService} from "../service/auth/auth.service";
  import {Observable} from "rxjs";

  @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
  })
  export class RoleGuard {
    constructor(private service: AuthService, private route: Router) {
    }
    
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
      //if(this.service.IsLoggedIn()) {
        console.log('RoleGuard: login olundu');
        const userRoles = this.service.getRoles();
        console.log(userRoles);

        if (userRoles) {
          // check if route is restricted by role
          const { roles } = route.data;


          if (!roles) {
            // role not authorized so redirect to home page
            //this.route.navigate(['']);
            console.log(roles)
            console.log(roles.includes(userRoles))
            console.log('RoleGuard: user not authorized')
            return false;
          }
          // authorized so return true
          console.log('RoleGuard: user authorized')
          return true;
        }
        console.log('RoleGuard: login değil');
        //this.route.navigate(['auth/login'])
      this.route.navigate(['auth/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
        return false;

      //} else {
      //  console.log('RoleGuard: not login');
      //  this.route.navigate(['auth/login'])
      //  return false;
      //}
    }
  }
```

**AuthService**

[image]

```
getRoles() {
  const loginToken = window.sessionStorage.getItem('access_permission_token') || '';
  const _extractedToken=loginToken.split('.')[1];
  const _atobData=atob(_extractedToken);
  const _finalData=JSON.parse(_atobData);
  return _finalData.resource_access.api_inventory.roles;
}
```

In this way, the roles of the user come and I redirect them on the routing-guard page, but it keeps getting "false" despite the authorization.

```
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
  const user = this.service.getRoles();
  if (user) {
    console.log(route.data['roles'])
    console.log(user)

    // check if route is restricted by role
    if (route.data['roles'] && route.data['roles'].indexOf(user) === -1) {
      // role not authorised so redirect to home page

      console.log('false')
      this.route.navigate(['/']);
      return false;
    }
    console.log('true')
    // authorised so return true
    return true;
  }

  // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
  this.route.navigate(['auth/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
  return false;
  }
```

Comment: I think the problem is const { roles } = route.data, you use deconstructor then you need to do const roles  = route.data.roles; and in the if you need to add a check || roles.length === 0; Let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming users will get access to the route if they have any of the roles that route is guarded with.You can try something like

```
 export class RoleGuard {
        constructor(private service: AuthService, private route: Router) {
        }
        
        canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {     
            const roles  = route.data.roles;//make sure you are getting the roles here
            if(!roles.length){
              return true; //no role applied on route so just return true
            } 
            const userRoles = this.service.getRoles();
            let isAuthrised=!!userRoles?.length && roles.some(r=>userRoles.includes(r))
            if (isAuthrised) {
              // authorized so return true
              console.log('RoleGuard: user authorized')
              return true;
            }
            console.log('RoleGuard: login değil');
            this.route.navigate(['auth/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
            return false;
    }
```

Comment: read the comment and then write the answer... nice work

Comment: @Den not sure what you are trying to say here `!!userRoles?.length && roles.some(r=>userRoles.includes(r))` This is the line that does the main check also there can be thousands of people who can think the same way so it's not necessary if someone includes part of your comment is copied it can be there own thinking as well